# Tkinter OptionMenu empty dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I have an OptionMenu widget that is usually filled with a list (like a course list).

```
    self.var_course = StringVar(self.add_window)
    if len(courses) > 0:
        self.var_course.set(self.courses.keys()[0])
    course_drop = OptionMenu(self.add_window, self.var_course, *self.courses).\
        grid(row=0, column=1)
    Button(self.add_window, text="New", height=1, width=1).\
        grid(row=0, column=2)
```

Sometimes, this list will be empty because the user has not added any classes.  This is causing an error in the creation of course_drop.

```
File "blah/blah/blahblablah", line 32, in blah
course_drop = OptionMenu(self.add_window, self.var_course, *self.courses).
\TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

When the dictionary has values, the code works fine, however when it is empty I get the above error.  I assume the empty dictionary (self.courses) is not seen as a variable and thus not enough are passed.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    course_drop = OptionMenu(self.add_window, self.var_course,
                  *self.courses).grid(row=0, column=1)
except TypeError:
    pass # display an error, prompt for something that will allow a retry, whatever
```

Another option:

```
    course_drop = OptionMenu(self.add_window, self.var_course,
                  *self.courses if self.courses else 0).grid(row=0, column=1)
                  # pick a default value that makes sense if 0 does not
```

Finally, keep in mind that `mywidget = Widget(option=value).grid()` assigns the `return` value of `grid()` to `mywidget`, which is `None`. You should `grid()` your widgets in a separate statement following their assignment.

Comment: The second option raises: ```TypeError: type object argument after * must be an iterable, not int```.